# How to boot to the recovery mode if it is not listed in Grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, recovery-mode

I want to boot Ubuntu into recovery mode but there is no grub menu entry allowing me to do so. I pressed `e` and now I am able to edit boot options. It looks like that:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu , with Linux 3.6.0-26-generic'

recordfail
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <uuid>
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=<uuid> ro ipv6.disable=1 quirt splash $vt_handoff
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-26-generic
```

The [menu editing examples](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting#Menu_Editing_Examples) documentation says:

> Boot to the recovery mode even if it is not listed on the menu:
>
> - Remove existing kernel options from the linux line and add single

But this sentence doesn't make any sense, maybe the wiki page is broken somehow. How to modify the **boot menu** to boot directly into recovery mode?

**Note**: I don't have access to grub config or anything else, only the boot menu edit page is available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The instruction `Remove existing kernel options from the linux line and add single` refers to changing the line

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=<uuid> ro ipv6.disable=1 quirt splash $vt_handoff
```

to

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=<uuid> single
```

which will boot up and show a text-mode terminal with root permissions ("single-user mode") from which fixes can be made.

The Ubuntu recovery mode is entered by setting `linux` options thusly:

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-26-generic root=<uuid> ro recovery nomodeset
```

This provides a menu which automates some common system fixes, or lets you access a root shell as the `single` option would.