# Forgot to install login screen after removing unity and installing kubuntu-desktop

Tags: lightdm, gdm

First I must admit that I did something really stupid.

I de-installed unity from my ubuntu 12.04 LTS to install kubuntu-desktop as I wanted to try out a different desktop environment.

The problem is that by de-installing unity it also de-installed my login screen.
Apparently ldm and gdm are not included in the kubuntu-desktop package.

Now this means that when I start my ubuntu with grub, I will get a black screen after the splash screen and I can not do anything. I can't open up a terminal, and I can't press ALT + F2 to install either one of them.

The disk is encrypted and I can not access it from my windows boot.
To make the situation even more dramatic: I saved the decrypt key on the same disk on a different partition.

Have I completely locked myself out?
Can I alter the grub configuration so that I can get a terminal after the splash?

While typing this I just came up with the idea to boot into my other linux OS on that same disk.
Maybe I can get something to work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot to recovery mode, drop to a root shell, and run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
apt-get update
apt-get install -f
apt-get install kdm
```

That should install and configure KDM. Reboot and post back if you have problems.

The only other potential problem you might have would be if you need propriety drivers , what graphics card do you have ?

Comment: I have messed up my grub a long time ago due to a tripple boot installation on my computer. 
Getting it back to work was not an easy task for me, so I used some tool to edit the grub menu. This is why I asked if grub menu can be altered.
I'm not sure what the name was again and I can't check that right now. 
This tool erased the recovery mode I had in my grub configuration.
This would've indeed been the simplest option if it were possible for me, but I am going to try maythux's solution as it is more relevant to my situation I guess.
I will report back in the morning after a good breakfast.

Comment: To "manually" boot to recovery mode, when booting, edit the grub boot options, and add the word "single" at the end of the linux line , see http://askubuntu.com/questions/326528/how-to-boot-to-the-recovery-mode-if-it-is-not-listed-in-grub and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: Thank you, I will try this immediately. I was searching for that.
My gratitude.

Comment: You are welcome and I made a small update to my answer ;)

Comment: Dear bodhi.zazen
thank you so much for helping me out so far. 
I got into my ubuntu installation again thanks to your support. 
I ran sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm to reset the login screen and this made it work for me.

As for your second question, yes I do beleave I have a problem with my Radeon HD5780 (5xxx) Graphics card. 
My windows have spastic tendencies whenever I move them around. Might you perhaps know of any answer to this weird phenomena? With spastic, ofcourse I mean to imply the kind of stuff you get to see when you don't have any drivers installed for a graphics card...

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I suggest you start a new question regarding yoru graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a live CD

chroot to your partition and you can easily install whatever u like.

---

You’ll want to boot from your Ubuntu Live CD, choosing “Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer” from the boot menu.

Once the system boots, open up a new Terminal window from Applications \ Accessories and then type in the following command:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This command is used to tell what device name the hard drive is using, which in most cases should be /dev/sda1, but could be different on your system.
[image]

Now you’ll need to create a directory to mount the hard drive on. Since we’re actually booting off the live cd, the directory doesn’t really get created anywhere.

```
sudo mkdir /media/sda1
```

The next command will mount the hard drive in the /media/sda1 folder.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/sda1
```

Now it’s time for the command that actually does the magic: chroot.

```
sudo chroot /media/sda1
```

Now you can do whatever you want then exit and unmount the mounted partitions and reboot

Comment: Just boot to recovery mode, much easier, especially considering the encryption.